# Fail to run fabric first network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When i am running the first network in fabric-samples by running the given command

```
./byfn.sh -m up
```

The client seems that it cannot do the query and produce the following console messages.

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...3 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...6 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...9 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...13 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...16 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...19 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...22 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...25 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...28 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...31 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...34 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...37 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...40 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...43 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...46 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...49 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...52 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...55 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...58 secs
Attempting to Query PEER0 ...61 secs

2017-09-14 08:28:34.964 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2017-09-14 08:28:34.964 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-09-14 08:28:34.964 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2017-09-14 08:28:34.964 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2017-09-14 08:28:34.965 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: plaintext: 0A95070A6708031A0C08B2FBE8CD0510...6D7963631A0A0A0571756572790A0161 
2017-09-14 08:28:34.965 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: digest: D5683DD12A1733A407FA3684BA9681BDA0B2FE178BCF313A2D9A96F31E6EDAD6 
Error: Error endorsing query: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = could not find chaincode with name 'mycc' - make sure the chaincode mycc has been successfully instantiated and try again - <nil>
Usage:
  peer chaincode query [flags]

Flags:
  -C, --channelID string   The channel on which this command should be executed (default "testchainid")
  -c, --ctor string        Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
  -x, --hex                If true, output the query value byte array in hexadecimal. Incompatible with --raw
  -n, --name string        Name of the chaincode
  -r, --raw                If true, output the query value as raw bytes, otherwise format as a printable string
  -t, --tid string         Name of a custom ID generation algorithm (hashing and decoding) e.g. sha256base64

Global Flags:
      --cafile string              Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --logging-level string       Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string             Ordering service endpoint
      --test.coverprofile string   Done (default "coverage.cov")
      --tls                        Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
  -v, --version                    Display current version of fabric peer server

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Query result on PEER0 is INVALID !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================== ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ==============
```

I CAN successfully launch it previously. But now i can not work at all! I try to put the network down and restart again. But it still does not work!

Anyone to help me?

Comment: What version of the Fabric images are you using?   If you were previously using the v1.0.0 images and updated them to v1.0.1 or v1.0.2, you should also make sure that you pull down the latest fabric-samples repo as well at the Fabric binaries associated with v1.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest cleaning things up and getting the latest images, binaries and updating your clone of the fabric-samples repo per http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html.

If you've already done that, you might want to make sure you run
`./byfn.sh -m generate` again